# Why do Daedalus Rewards Report Epoch End Dates differ from other sources?

Tags: staking, daedalus, rewards, epoch

So I exported my latest rewards report to CSV, as Daedalus allows. The date on the report is April 30, 2021.

If I query the blockchain for my rewards history, the latest rewards I have received are from epoch 261 (Daedalus says we're currently on epoch 263).
Epoch 261 ended on April 25. Why does the report say April 30?

When I check my rewards history on `adastat.net`, the date on the latest rewards, labeled as from epoch 261, is April 30.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewards for a given epoch X are paid out at the end of the next epoch, X+1. This is because the calculation of which stake keys get rewards is done during epoch X+1.

Applying this to your example, the order of events would be:

1. April 25th - epoch 261 ends
2. April 30th - epoch 262 ends - rewards from epoch 261 are paid
3. April 30th - epoch 263 starts - CSV report and adastat.net list current date and epoch.

The terminology of rewards being "paid" is somewhat misleading, since there are no transactions that correspond to the rewards entering your wallet. Instead, the amount of rewards for all stake keys is stored separately in the ledger, and that table is updated on epoch boundaries. Your private stake key then allows you to withdraw/send the rewards along with regular transactions.

Comment: If you combine our answers, I will delete mine.

Comment: @gRebel I've included your answer verbatim, thanks!

Comment: and improved on it.