# Overlap in epochs

Tags: epoch

Is there an actual overlap in epochs (see https://poolpeek.com/#/epochcalendar)? If so why? Or is this only an allowance for timezones, or are epochs somewhat unpredictable.  On a related note on https://adapools.org/epochs most epochs are 120 hours, but some are 119.9 hours. Why?
Sorry, Probably a noob question but [Why do Daedalus Rewards Report Epoch End Dates differ from other sources?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/290/why-do-daedalus-rewards-report-epoch-end-dates-differ-from-other-sources) doesn't quite seem relevant to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`epoch` and `slots` are effectively just ways to express time from start of the chain. What you're looking at on adapools is likely the difference between first and last block within an epoch. You can check the epoch start/end time of given epoch, as well as first/last block of epoch at [koios](https://api.koios.rest/#get-/epoch_info)

Answer (score 1):

No, epochs do not overlap. They are also 100% deterministic and exactly 120 hours long (on mainnet).

I cannot answer questions about poolpeek.

Answer (score 1):

The overlap shown is because of the display format of full days. The epoch transitions at 21:44:51 every 5 days, so for most of the day it will be previous epoch and last few hours it will be the new epoch.